# VisualSVN change existing URL

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

The company I work for has updated it's DNS server and changed it's name.  Now I can't get VisualSVN to accept the change.

The URL was `https://dev.xyzdns.local:8443/svn/project` and now it needs to be `https://dev.xyz.local:8443/svn/project`. If I try to change the URL in Visual Studio 2010, it comes up with the switch to branch window, I click OK and it tells me that the old and new repository are not the same. I've also tried manually going through the registry and the VisualSVN folders and changing references to the new DNS name and to no avail. If it matters, the SVN server and primary development computer are the same.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you queried this with VisualSVN themselves? http://www.visualsvn.com/support/

Comment: Did you actually change the URL in VisualSVN? If not, what error do you get?

Answer (score 9):

Use TortoiseSVN, rightclick the top most folder you checked-out your svn repository to on your harddrive.

```
Select TortoiseSVN --> Relocate.
```

Simply type in the new url, and click OK.
Without even restarting Visual studio, you can commit/update  with the new url.

Answer (score 4):

VisualSVN is only for visual studio integration. This type of work needs to be done outside VS and with the TortoiseSVN Shell itself.

The specific TortoiseSVN command is "Relocate":

> If your repository has for some reason changed it's location (IP/URL).
>   Maybe you're even stuck and can't commit and you don't want to
>   checkout your working copy again from the new location and to move all
>   your changed data back into the new working copy, TortoiseSVN →
>   Relocate is the command you are looking for. It basically does very
>   little: it scans all entries files in the .svn folder and changes the
>   URL of the entries to the new value.

**Edit**
From the OP's comments, if you just want to start from scratch and not retain any history:

1. Perform an "export" of your project from your existing repository. This will simply download your project without any SVN hooks.
2. Create a new and empty project on your SVN Server. (this is step 1 in the below steps)

From here, you'll want to perform what is known as an "Import in Place":

> **4.2.2. Import in Place**
>
> Assuming you already have a repository, and you
>   want to add a new folder structure to it, just follow these steps:
>
> 1. Use the repository browser to create a new project folder directly in
>      the repository.
> 2. Checkout the new folder over the top of the folder you want to import.
>      You will get a warning that the local folder is not empty. Now you
>      have a versioned top level folder with unversioned content.
> 3. Use TortoiseSVN → Add... on this versioned folder to add some or all
>      of the content. You can add and remove files, set svn:ignore
>      properties on folders and make any other changes you need to.
> 4. Commit the top level folder, and you have a new versioned tree, and a
>      local working copy, created from your existing folder.

Comment: say i was fine with 'losing' all the previous versions and i just want to start from basically scratch, will the relocate do that? Or how can i take the existing project and force it into a brand new repository?

Comment: See my edits for importing in place. Alternatively, you could use the "branch" command, but that will create a link to the old project and isn't really want you're trying to achieve. The import in place is what you are looking for.

Comment: It's as simple as right-clicking the folder containing your files then: TortoiseSVN -> Relocate -> Type in the new url.

Comment: @wmcainsh - this answer already addresses the use of "Relocate". Please read the answer in full which addresses relocate as well as the OP's follow up question.